# Is it possible to modify VS project file during NuGet package installation?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I'd like to create a custom MSBuild task and distribute it as a NuGet package. To enable my task, the visual studio proj file should be modified.

Is it possible to add my code sections to the proj file when installing the NuGet package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using Powershell. It is possible to unload you project, edit the project file and reload the project.

Scott Hanselman did this here: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM09

If you find a package that does what you want, you can open the nuget package using ZIP and see the powershell scripts. Thats a good starting point to learn that stuff.

hope that helps

Comment: Why is there so little documentation for using install scripts with nuget packages...

Answer (score 4):

I think you are better off using the NuGetPowerTools package as answered in this question:

[Adding a custom build step with a nuget package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521751/adding-a-custom-build-step-with-a-nuget-package)

This package handles all the Visual Studio automation.