# NuGet - Dependee project referencing different DLL according to selected build configuration

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I'm completely new to NuGet and just researching/proof-of-concept'ing it at the moment:

Is it possible to package a NuGet package in such a way that the dependee project (the one that has the dependency) references a different DLL according to the project configuration build?

Example:

```
Dependee-Debug.DLL -> References Dependency-Debug.DLL
Dependee-Release.DLL -> References Dependecy-Release.DLL
```

Similarly, I'd need to repeat this behaviour for 32-bit/64-bit discrimination. If this is possible, is there a tutorial that explains how, anywhere? I can't find any mention of this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to reference different assemblies based on the current build configuration by using either a PowerShell script or using custom MSBuild targets file. Note that using an MSBuild targets file will work cross platform in MonoDevelop and Xamarin Studio where as a PowerShell script will not.

NuGet allows you to include an MSBuild targets file so you can change what happens at build time. In the MSBuild targets file you can have the references and make them conditional based on the current build configuration.

In the build directory of your NuGet package you add an MSBuild .targets file with the same name as your NuGet package id. You can also have different .targets files for a particular target framework (e.g. Net40) by having it under a Net40 subdirectory if you need to.

```
build\MyPackageId.targets
```

Then in the MSBuild .targets file you can do something simple such as have the references conditionally added.

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x86' ">
    <Reference Include="MyAssembly">
      <HintPath>x86\MyAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64' ">
    <Reference Include="MyAssembly">
      <HintPath>x64\MyAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I am having some trouble getting this working.  Could you post some more code?  It doesn't seem to be using my reference.  So my code isn't compiling: CS0246 The type or namespace name could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run PowerShell scripts during package install to edit the CSPROJ file to conditionally reference different dependencies.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758147/is-it-possible-to-modify-vs-project-file-during-nuget-package-installation) question for a couple of useful links.